# How to load a nested relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationships

I have a model called CallbackRequest the model has a relationship with Loan model and that is the only relationship for CallbackRequest model.

CallbackModel:

```
public function loan() {

    return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class);
}
```

Now Loan model itself has a relationship with a third model called Applicant.

Loan Model:

```
public function applicant() {

    return $this->belongsTo(Applicant::class);
}
```

My point:

When I load CallbackRequest I eagerload loan model with it, all fine! But now I am wondering if there is a way to eagerload applicant model when I do:

Right now I access it like:

```
$modelResults = PublicCallback::with('loan')->get();
```

I get all callbacks with loan eagerloaded, but my point is I want when I eagerload loans in this case I want applicant to be loaded also !

Is there any way how to do this, is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
$modelResults = PublicCallback::with(['loan', 'loan.applicant'])->get();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: well well well well

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, there's also another way of loading nested relationships that can be done against a returned model, provided you have set up the relationships correctly:

Posts model:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'quote_id', 'id');
}
```

Comments model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then you can actually infer the user via relationship to a comment by drawing the post but loading an array of relations, eg:

```
$post = \App\Post::find($post_id);
return $post->load(['comments','comments.user']);
```